# Choosing a configuration for a ruby-graphql based rails application with websockets

Tags: websocket, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a ruby-graphql based application which has an inbuilt chat functionality. I have tried various combinations of configurations but I'm always stuck with a problem. The app server stops responding sporadically when websocket connections are established. Upon refreshing the page on the client machine the server starts to respond again.

Things that I have tried -

1. Running action-cable with my web-app.
2. Running action-cable as a separate rack app.
3. Trying 1 and 2 with puma and phusion-passenger separately.
4. Upgrading the hardware on which the app run to upto 8 times.

Things that I'm considering -

1. Using a different server for the websockets all together.
2. Trying out anycable/ anycable-go on that separate server.

The app server logs, when it freezes only say 
`himanshu821@hornet:/var/deploy/educatly_staging/web_head/current/log$ tail -f staging.log
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.873327 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:16
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871591 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:4
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871648 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:14
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871698 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:40
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871744 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:44
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871789 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:15
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871897 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:18
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871946 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:20
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.871992 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:23
I, [2018-12-20T12:25:05.872107 #9916]  INFO -- : [ActionCable] [User 6] ConversationsChannel is streaming from conversations:21`

I've analysed the server at this state with htop, it utilizes about 10-20% of the hardware.

Has someone had this kind of a problem before ? If yes am I heading in the right direction or there could be a different problem altogether ?